# How to store imageview after picking it from gallery

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, gallery

I'm making a user profile which the user can change his profile picture, but I want the selected image to be stored and not to disappear after I go to another activity, I already did the selecting image from the gallery part. I know this has something to do with `shared preferences` or bitmap coding but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

How can I do that exactly, and thank you.

Comment: can you share your code so far

Comment: i only did the picking image part , take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826008/how-to-save-images-to-imageview-using-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

First covert the Image Path you get into Base64 String using this function

```
public static String getFileToByte(String path){
  Bitmap bm = null;
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
  byte[] b = null;
  String encodeString = null;
   try{
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
    b = baos.toByteArray();
    encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
  }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return encodeString;
 }
```

Save the Base64 in SharedPreferences

```
    SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("image_data",getFileToByte("/path/to/image.jpg"));
edit.commit();
```

Show it back in IMAGEVIEW when needed

```
    SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");

if( !previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: thanks , do you have a github project using this method ?

Comment: can't reslove method equals ?

Comment: can you explain this please getFileToByte("/path/to/image.jpg"));

Comment: /path/to/image.jpg is (u get image uri in after picking image from gallery) covert uri to path and pass it

Comment: you mean i have to do it manually ? that means everytime i want to save an image i have to set the path myself right ?

Comment: no you can get from picked image see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20324422/4044380